# Python-Unique ID Generator Code

Tags: python, function, variables, string-concatenation, uniqueidentifier

I have a function in which I want to give a string and then I want it to return a code where the first 6 digits are random and unique and then I have a dash and then the last digits display a 000 (if the last 4 digits are 0000) or a 00X (if the last 4 digits are 0X00) where X is a number from 0-9.

ex: if I give the function '60817409470000' it should return 627861-000
and if I give it '60817409470100' it should return  627861-001. 
where 627861 was generated in a random sequence and should not be repeated

so far I have the following and I'm getting stuck at concatenating the string generated randomly with the extension

```
import random as r
from random import randint 

UI=''
srng='60817409470100'

def ui_Gen(srng):

    unid = str((randint(100000,999999))

    if srng[10:14] =='0000':
        UI= str((randint(100000,999999)) +'000'
    else:
        UI = unid + '00' + srng[11]

    return UI
```

Any thoughts on how to do this better?

Comment: What is wrong with your code?

Comment: Why do you treat `0000` as a special case even though it's no different from the `0X00` thing? Your function could be reduced to a single line of code.

Comment: I see your point with respect to my code. You mean: I don't need an else statement. 0000 symbolizes as the origin.

Comment: The code is giving me a syntax error:  File "<ipython-input-1-3fa625db4d24>", line 11
    if srng[10:14] =='0000':
                           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Answer (score 0):

Just use the uuid python module:

[uuid](https://docs.python.org/2/library/uuid.html)

Comment: True but it's not completely random, as I need a shared key between the parent '0000' and the children: '0100','0200',0300'